# Generalizations of the Robbins lemma and Gaussian integration by parts

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-distributions, empirical-bayes

- The Robbins lemma, named after Herbert Robbins, says that if $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $g$ is a function for which $\operatorname{E}(|X g(X)|) < \infty,$ then $$\operatorname{E}(Xg(X)) = \lambda \operatorname{E}(g(X+1)).$$
- "Gaussian integration by parts" is an identity that says that under suitable assumptions about the function $g$, if $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2),$ then $$ \operatorname{E}(Xg(X)) = \sigma^2\operatorname{E} (g\,'(X)). $$

Both of these propositions are used in empirical Bayes methods.

Both of these are of the form $$ \operatorname{E}(Xg(X)) = \operatorname{var}(X) \cdot \operatorname{E} ((Tg)(X)) $$
where $T$ is a linear operator on functions $g$.

**QUESTION:** Might there be, for each linear operator $T$, some probability distribution for which this holds? And might all of these be useful in empirical Bayes methods?

Comment: I'm half-way expecting someone will explain how this is all just integration by parts.

Comment: I see that you have created ([tag:empirical-bayes]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/empirical-bayes/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. (This is probably not a problem here, since the tag name seems to be descriptive enough.) Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).